# CSS: Align grid header with grid elements

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid layout in CSS. I want to put a header above the grid. I want the left edge of the header to align with the left edge of the first item in the grid. I have created a snippet of my grid. See how when you drag the grid's container to resize it the width between the grid's elements and the edge of the container is not the same.

How do I make my header align with the leftmost edge of the grid elements?

Edit: I want the grid items to be centered when there is extra horizontal space. Setting `justify-content: left;` is not the solution.

```css
.page {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 12px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 140px);
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.grid-element {
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 82px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <p>Grid Header</p>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: apply ``justify-content: left;`` insted of ``justify-content: center;`` to ``.grid`` class

Comment: But I want the grid items to align in the center when there is remaining space.

Comment: why are you not using bootstrap grid layout its a best and very easy to set the every grid element no more used css you can used the col-sm-4 col-xs-12 etc

Comment: Because it is less flexible in changing the amount of columns based on available width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply add the title as an element inside the grid that span all the first row

```css
.page {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 12px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 140px);
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.grid-element {
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 82px;
  background: white;
}
.grid  p {
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column:1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="grid">
    <p>Grid Header</p>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

added `justify-content: flex-start;` to `.grid` class hope this helps you. thanks

```css
.page {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 12px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 140px);
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.grid-element {
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 82px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <p>Grid Header</p>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I want the grid items to align in the center when there is extra space.

Answer (score -1):

You can give it a class, then use margin to align it.